# how to use font-awesome in a disconnected environment?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I need to support my application in environment without access to the internet, it runs on intranets only. This means that I can use the font-awesome in the following fashion:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

how do I go about using this font?
I also see that I can install the npm package, but I still dont see the font, using an arrow, being displayed.

Any insights?

Comment: Host the font file and the CSS on your own server.

Answer (score 1):

You can just download the Font Awesome source and link the `href` to your local directory. Here's a link to the latest version: http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can download the font-awesome file in your system. Provide them a path and refer them where you want to use it.

Currently you are accessing them through CDN.

here: http://fontawesome.io/